# Get port on which Android app start

Tags: android, linux, terminal, port, root

We have:

1) Rooted device

2) Started app on it. (YouTube for example).

3) PID of this app.

4) Some data transfer from internet to app. (Video play)

I need to get port to which this data transfer.

P.S.  With help of "tcpdump" i can to see on which port data is transfer, but there can be a lot of port on which data sending. I need only for my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
cat /proc/pid/net/tcp
```

my mistake was what this command need to call than Video is playing, be cause new ports add to app *tcp* file only than it need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsof -i` to get all the open internet connections. To extract you app you can do the following:

```
     lsof -i | grep "yourappname"
```

This will give you the connection information like, which ip:port is used to communicate with remote server.

Comment: lsof in Android Terminal can't parse parametrs(

Comment: I've tested it on my version of busybox, which worked. And this is usual way of seeing open internet connection with app,port,ip etc. This should work :-/

Comment: It works but gives the same result every time. There is no differents between lsof -h and lsof or lsof -i.